# Size of @Lob annotation column to accept multiple large files of around 100 mb

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to upload multiple files in MySQL database. I am using Multipart to achieve it. While defining the Model 'FileDB', I came across an issue with size of Column that stores the Attached Documents.
My requirement is the Database Column should store list of Documents I will upload i.e 120 MB of files for one record. Is it possible? How should I specify the size of column through Spring Boot

```
package springboot.uploadfilesdatabase.model;


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Lob;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class FileDB {


      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    
      private long id;

      private String name;
      
      private String type;

      @Lob
      @Column(length = "?")
      private byte[] data;
      
      
    
}
```

I tried without specifying length, but its throwing Exception That I have designed.
As per my understandings, The appropriate size is not specified during Entity Code.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)